# Using FTGL with Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I am trying to build a project(logstalgia) with emscripten, but the project requires the ftgl dev libraries (libftgl-dev). I have been searching around for the correct way to link this library so I can run `shell> emconfigure logstalgia/configure`, but I can't figure out how to compile and link this library into the project.

I have read the emscripten documentation, but unfortunately it has been years since I have used gcc or written a makefile.

Emscripten says `"Other libraries not included with emscripten, like boost, you would need to compile yourself and link with your program, just as if they were a module in your project."` Unfortunately I do not have enough previous knowledge to know what this wants me to do. I understand the concept but have no idea how to go about executing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can ftgl work on top of OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: Maybe this should help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724357/using-boost-with-emscripten

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build FTGL with Emscripten first, then link your application with the library your built.

But as other mentioned, first you need to check if FTGL supports OpenGL ES 2.0 since WebGL 1.0 is the same as targeting GLES2.

If not, you can always try the experimental WebGL 2.0 support, which is the same as targeting Open GL ES 3.0.