# Building boost with emscripten

Tags: c++, boost, emscripten

I'm trying to port a c++ project to the web using Emscripten.
For that purpose, I need to build libraries into llvm bytecode (.bc).
I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724357/using-boost-with-emscripten) that may have helped, unfortunately it didn't work for me.
I run into hundreds of errors.
Here is a sample:

```
erasme:~/Sources/boost$ ./b2
ERROR    root: no input files
```

...

```
libs/context/src/unsupported.cpp:7:2: error: "platform not supported"
#error "platform not supported"
 ^
1 error generated.
ERROR    root: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

Has anyone built boost with emscripten? How?

Thank you for your answers.
Erasme.

Comment: A few of us actually tried. Due to boosts proprietary build system it is actually really difficult to port/compile it to Emscripten.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Boost with Emscripten](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724357/using-boost-with-emscripten)

Comment: @abergmeier: boost's build system is not proprietary, it's simply not as common as things like make and cmake. it is fully open source and is used regularly in a small minority of open source c++ projects. probably the main advantage over cmake is that it can be used easily in appveyor CI builds, because when it targets msvc, it actually runs the msvc c++ compiler at the command line simliarly to how it treats gcc and clang, rather than trying to emit an msvc project file.