# building boost with emscripten on windows

Tags: windows, boost, build, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to build boost using emscripten on windows. In particular, I am trying to use the emscripten toolset as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751199/5969590. However, this produces the following error for me:

```
C:\dev\emsdk\python\3.9.2-1_64bit\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\dev\boost_1_76_0\emcc.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Somewhere in the toolchain boost tries to invoke emcc.py using python, but fails by passing the wrong module path (there is no `emcc.py` in `c:\dev\boost_1_76_0\`).

- I made sure path environment variables are setup correctly by executing `emsdk_env.bat`. Running `emcc.bat` (which internally runs `emcc.py`) manually, executes the compiler as expected.
- I inserted some debug printouts in `emcc.bat` and from that I gather that the boost toolchain is not using that file. It seems it tries to use python and `emcc.py` directly. This seems to be where things break down.

Any help or hint is greatly appreciated.

Best,
David

Answer (score 1):

Problem was related to this: [What is the reason for batch file path referenced with %~dp0 sometimes changes on changing directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141482/what-is-the-reason-for-batch-file-path-referenced-with-dp0-sometimes-changes-o)

I solved the problem by hacking emcc.bat to use hardcoded path to the emcc.py file.