# How can I properly link Boost when compiling with Emscripten?

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, emscripten, boost-filesystem

How can I properly link Boost when compiling with Emscripten?

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::filesystem::exists("file.txt");
}
```

Compile and link:

```
> em++ main.cpp --use-ports=boost_headers -sUSE_BOOST_HEADERS=1 -lboost_headers
wasm-ld: error: /tmp/emscripten_temp_u68f6vxm/main_0.o: undefined symbol: boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)
em++: error: '/home/ubuntu/tmp/emscripten/emsdk/upstream/bin/wasm-ld -o a.out.wasm /tmp/emscripten_temp_u68f6vxm/main_0.o -L/home/ubuntu/tmp/emscripten/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten /home/ubuntu/tmp/emscripten/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libboost_headers.a -lGL-getprocaddr -lal -lhtml5 -lstubs-debug -lnoexit -lc-debug -ldlmalloc -lcompiler_rt -lc++-noexcept -lc++abi-debug-noexcept -lsockets -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr /tmp/tmpv1sq5rj0libemscripten_js_symbols.so --strip-debug --export=emscripten_stack_get_end --export=emscripten_stack_get_free --export=emscripten_stack_get_base --export=emscripten_stack_get_current --export=emscripten_stack_init --export=stackAlloc --export=stackSave --export=stackRestore --export=__get_temp_ret --export=__set_temp_ret --export=__wasm_call_ctors --export-if-defined=__start_em_asm --export-if-defined=__stop_em_asm --export-if-defined=__start_em_lib_deps --export-if-defined=__stop_em_lib_deps --export-if-defined=__start_em_js --export-if-defined=__stop_em_js --export-if-defined=main --export-if-defined=__main_argc_argv --export-if-defined=fflush --export-table -z stack-size=65536 --initial-memory=16777216 --max-memory=16777216 --no-entry --stack-first --table-base=1' failed (returned 1)
```

With `-lboost_filesystem`:

```
wasm-ld: error: unable to find library -lboost_filesystem
```

## Building Boost from source

```
git clone --recursive --branch=boost-1.83.0 --depth=1 https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
cd boost

# Without specifying a toolset, it shows the help
# When specifying --with-toolset=emscripten, it says toolset emscripten not recognized
# b2 is generated --with-toolset=gcc
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc

# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751199/16847511
./b2 toolset=emscripten
```

The last command (`./b2 toolset=emscripten`) gives an error:

```
emcc: warning: .bc output file suffix used without -flto or -emit-llvm.  Consider using .o extension since emcc will output an object file, not a bitcode file [-Wemcc]
emscripten.archive bin.v2/libs/log/build/emscripten-3.1.55/release/link-static/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_log.bc
bin.v2/libs/log/build/emscripten-3.1.55/release/link-static/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/attribute_name.bc:1:2: error: expected top-level entity
```

Using [`emconfigure ./b2 toolset=gcc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59170762/16847511) works, but builds a regular version, not one suitable for Emscripten. Using my first code snippet as an example:

```
> em++ main.cpp --use-ports=boost_headers -sUSE_BOOST_HEADERS=1 -lboost_headers -lboost_filesystem -L/tmp/boost/stage/lib
wasm-ld: warning: /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: archive member 'codecvt_error_category.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: archive member 'exception.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: archive member 'directory.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: archive member 'operations.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: archive member 'path.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: archive member 'path_traits.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: archive member 'portability.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: archive member 'unique_path.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: warning: /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: archive member 'utf8_codecvt_facet.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode
wasm-ld: error: /tmp/emscripten_temp_k9_q4uwl/simple-boost_0.o: undefined symbol: boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)
em++: error: '/home/ubuntu/tmp/emscripten/emsdk/upstream/bin/wasm-ld -o a.out.wasm /tmp/emscripten_temp_k9_q4uwl/simple-boost_0.o /home/ubuntu/tmp/emscripten/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libboost_headers.a /tmp/boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a -L/tmp/boost/stage/lib -L/home/ubuntu/tmp/emscripten/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten /home/ubuntu/tmp/emscripten/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libboost_headers.a -lGL-getprocaddr -lal -lhtml5 -lstubs-debug -lnoexit -lc-debug -ldlmalloc -lcompiler_rt -lc++-noexcept -lc++abi-debug-noexcept -lsockets -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr /tmp/tmp2dceaguelibemscripten_js_symbols.so --strip-debug --export=emscripten_stack_get_end --export=emscripten_stack_get_free --export=emscripten_stack_get_base --export=emscripten_stack_get_current --export=emscripten_stack_init --export=stackAlloc --export=stackSave --export=stackRestore --export=__get_temp_ret --export=__set_temp_ret --export=__wasm_call_ctors --export-if-defined=__start_em_asm --export-if-defined=__stop_em_asm --export-if-defined=__start_em_lib_deps --export-if-defined=__stop_em_lib_deps --export-if-defined=__start_em_js --export-if-defined=__stop_em_js --export-if-defined=main --export-if-defined=__main_argc_argv --export-if-defined=fflush --export-table -z stack-size=65536 --initial-memory=16777216 --max-memory=16777216 --no-entry --stack-first --table-base=1' failed (returned 1)
```

Comment: you've only linked to the boost headers, filesystem isn't a header-only library

Comment: @AlanBirtles is that true even with Emscripten? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60550627/16847511

Comment: don't think so https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html `In the specific case of Boost, if you only need the boost headers then you don’t need to compile anything.`

Comment: do you really need boost::filesystem? will std::filesystem do instead?

Comment: @AlanBirtles then how would I include not just Boost headers, but also the Boost libraries? I do need Boost because I'm trying to compile someone else's code, not my own (they also use other Boost features).

Comment: @drescherjm which answer do you mean? the [newest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60550627/16847511) suggests using `-s USE_BOOST_HEADERS=1`, which I have already tried (see post). This answer has 9 upvotes.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=boost+filesystem+emscripten+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: "building boost from source / The last command gives an error:" - it doesn't for me: https://i.imgur.com/zaOiwBA.png no idea how to make it use that, but I'll try some more

Comment: Oh I think I'm seeing it already

Comment: @sehe your screenshot shows version 1.85 (master, unstable), but I'm using 1.83. Could that be the problem? yours also show `target-os-unknown` (I'm using x86_64 Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: Calm down :) You're already editing the question every 10s. I don't think I can keep up with comments at the same pace.

Comment: So yeah, that's an error specific to that release. Turns out downloading it all again for 1.83 was timeconsuming. And it ended me up with a shallow checkout, which it seems hard to switch / bisect tags with. So, maybe you'll just switch to 1.84, hopefully

Comment: @sehe can I ignore the fact that the [current latest Emscripten Boost port](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/boost/releases/latest) is version 1.83? (will it cause issues when I link with `-lboost_headers -lboost_filesystem`?)

Comment: @FromTheStackAndBack if you do it wrong enough, yeah. Just don't mix the two! I'll write up how I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying with the `develop` branch it worked nicely for me.

Per your request I verified using the 1.83.0 branch checkout, and sure enough, I ran into the build errors.

So I'd suggest you to build your own 1.84.0 (or `develop`) version which apparently has that fixed.

Of course, don't use the headers from `--use-ports`. Instead, use the headers from your own checkout:

```
em++ main.cpp -I ~/custom/boost/ -L ~/custom/boost/stage/lib/ -lboost_filesystem
```

The `-I` flag tells the compiler where to find includes.

The `-L` flag tells the linker where to find the shared libraries.

And here's it working nicely using my `develop` build (which reports as 1.85.0):

[image]

Comment: I just tried 1.84.0 and still get the error. Will try `develop` and see if it's a me problem, or a Boost problem.

Comment: Latest `develop` branch (commit `b1f5fe74f1c77866adb36f5d6fd116ea421dc68a`) confirmed to be working.

Comment: Great. Thanks for finally pushing me to try emscripten. It seems pretty awesome!